# Android- Same countdown timer for all the time zones

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datetime-format, countdowntimer

I need to show a same Countdown timer for all the time zones of USA.

I am getting end date time ie.(Wed Nov 30 12:00:00 PST 2022, Wed Nov30 12:00:00 EST 2022, WedNov 30 12:00:00 MST 2022)as per time zone from server but I want to show timer as PST time zone, by changing the time zone the remaining time in countdown timer should remain same ie. if it shown 1 day 7 hours 20 min for PST so it should be shown 1 day 7 hours 20 min if user in EST location ..which mean changing the time zone should not change the countdown timer .it should be the respective to PST time only.

```
fun countdownTimer(endDate: Date): Long {
val ldt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
val localtimeInPST: ZonedDateTime = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
val endDateInPSTLocalTime: ZonedDateTime =
    endDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
return endDateInPSTLocalTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli() - localtimeInPST.toInstant()
    .toEpochMilli()
```

}

I am using this code but when I am changing the time zone of device manually the countdown timer is also changing accordingly, but I want to keep same as what is showing in case of PST for all zones

Answer (score 0):

It will take up the systems default zone id and therefore whenever you are changing the timezone in your phone your timer change.

```
ZoneId.systemDefault()
```

Try replacing the above line with PST timezone id.

Comment: Not working,still countdown timer value getting changed